# Count repeating integers in an array

Tags: matlab, sorting, vector, sequence, counting

If I have this vector:

```
x = [1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 4 4 6 6 6 6]
```

I would like to get the position of each unique number according to itself.

```
y = [1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 1 1 2 1 2 3 4]
```

At the moment I'm using:

```
y = sum(triu(x==x.')) % MATLAB 2016b and above
```

It's compact but obviously not memory efficient.

For the pure beauty of MATLAB programming I would avoid using a loop. Do you have a better simple implementation ?

Context:

My final goal is to sort the vector `x` but with the constraint that a number that appear `N` times has the priority over another number that has appeared more than `N` times:

```
[~,ind] = sort(y);
x_relative_sort = x(ind);
% x_relative_sort = 1   2   3   4   6   1   2   4   6   1   2   6   1   6   1
```

Comment: Is `x = [1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 4 4 6 6 6 6 1 1 1]` a possible input? I men, can a number appear in two separate runs?

Comment: It could be the raw input, but for making things easier i've already sorted the array. Of course if you can find a solution that work in both case without using the sort function it's still better !

Comment: Funny that this has been [asked on PPCG](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/178500/36398). Maybe some of the solutions will give you some ideas

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming `x` is sorted, here's one vectorized alternative using [`unique`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html), [`diff`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html), and [`cumsum`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html):

```
[~, index] = unique(x);
y = ones(size(x));
y(index(2:end)) = y(index(2:end))-diff(index).';
y = cumsum(y);
```

And now you can apply your final sorting:

```
>> [~, ind] = sort(y);
>> x_relative_sort = x(ind)

x_relative_sort =

     1     2     3     4     6     1     2     4     6     1     2     6     1     6     1
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have positive integers you can use sparse matrix:

```
[y ,~] = find(sort(sparse(1:numel(x), x, true), 1, 'descend'));
```

Likewise `x_relative_sort` can directly be computed:

```
[x_relative_sort ,~] = find(sort(sparse(x ,1:numel(x),true), 2, 'descend'));
```

Answer (score 4):

Just for variety, here's a solution based on [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html). It works for `x` sorted and containing positive integers, as in the question:

```
y = cell2mat(accumarray(x(:), x(:), [], @(t){1:numel(t)}).');
```

Answer (score 4):

You can be more memory efficient by only comparing to `unique(x)`, so you don't have a large `N*N` matrix but rather `N*M`, where `N=numel(x), M=numel(unique(x))`.

I've used an anonymous function syntax to avoid declaring an intermediate matrix variable, needed as it's used twice - this can probably be improved.

```
f = @(X) sum(cumsum(X,2).*X); y = f(unique(x).'==x);
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's my solution that doesn't require sorting:

```
x = [1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 4 4 6 6 6 6 1 1 1];
y = cell2mat( splitapply(@(v){cumsum(v)},x,cumsum(logical([1 diff(x)]))) ) ./ x;
```

Explanation:

```
% Turn each group new into a unique number:
t1 = cumsum(logical([1 diff(x)]));
%  x = [1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 4 4 6 6 6 6 1 1 1];
% t1 = [1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 4 4 5 5 5 5 6 6 6];

% Apply cumsum separately to each group:
t2 = cell2mat( splitapply(@(v){cumsum(v)},x,t1) );
% t1 = [1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 4 4 5  5  5  5 6 6 6];
% t2 = [1 2 3 4 5 2 4 6 3 4 8 6 12 18 24 1 2 3];

% Finally, divide by x to get the increasing values:
y = t2 ./ x;
%  x = [1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 4 4 6  6  6  6 1 1 1];
% t2 = [1 2 3 4 5 2 4 6 3 4 8 6 12 18 24 1 2 3];
```