# Running sequence by group

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have a matrix containing group identifiers:

```
A = [ 1 ; 1 ; 2;2;2;3;3]
```

and I would like to enhance this by a running sequence by group to obtain a matrix like this:

```
B = [ 1,1 ; 1,2 ; 2,1;2,2;2,3;3,1;3,2]

B =

 1     1
 1     2
 2     1
 2     2
 2     3
 3     1
 3     2
```

How can I do this without using the dreaded for-loop? Thank you!

Comment: Is the last one `3,2`?

Comment: @OmG yes indeed, thank you!

Comment: What if there's a new `2` after the run of `3`'2? That is, what's the output for `A = [ 1 ; 1 ; 2;2;2;3;3;2]`?

Comment: Even if the above is not possible, would an input `A = [2;2; 1;1;1; 3;3]` be possible? Or `A=[1;1; 4;4; 5]`? Some approaches could benefit from the input being sorted, or not having gaps, or not having more than one run of each value. Please specify if any of those restrictions applies in your problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count repeating integers in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54079558/count-repeating-integers-in-an-array)

Comment: For small vector you can use: `B = [A,sum(triu(A==A.'),1).']`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Input contains positive integers, not necessarily consecutive but sorted

```
[B, ~] = find(sort(sparse(1:numel(A), A, true), 1, 'descend'));
B = [A B];
```

This works as follows:

1. Create an intermediate logical sparse matrix, with column positions determined by `A` and consecutive row positions: `sparse(1:numel(A), A, true)`. Although this matrix may be large, creating it as sparse makes the approach memory-efficient.
2. Move the  `true` entries in each column to the upper part of the matrix: `sort(..., 1, , 'descend')`.
3. The row indices contain the desired result: `[B, ~] = find(...)`.

## Input contains positive integers, not necessarily consecutive, not necessarily sorted

```
t = sparse(1:numel(A), A, true);
t = t.*cumsum(t, 1);
B = [A nonzeros(t.')];
```

This works as follows:

1. Create an intermediate logical sparse matrix as before.
2. In each column, replace nonzeros by consecutive values `1`, `2`, ...
3. Transpose the matrix. The nonzeros in linear order are the desired result.

Comment: Your approach seems to require, contrary to your stated assumptions, that the input matrix A is sorted. E.g. here it fails: A = [ 2 ; 1; 2; 3 ; 3;1;3]. But that's ok, I can sort the matrix.

Comment: I have also included a slightly different approach that works for the unsorted case

Comment: Seems to me it also works without creating a full matrix, quite a bit faster for large input matrix..

Comment: @bonifaz Thank you for the correction (I used `full` for debugging and forgot to remove it). I have edited that and added an explanation

Answer (score 0):

This works for nonintegers.

```
[s, is] = sort(A)
[~, d] = cummax(s) ;
C(is, :) = (2:numel(A) + 1).'  -  d;
B = [A C] ;
```

If input is sorted:

```
[~, d] = cummax(A) ;
C = (2:numel(A) + 1).'  -  d;
B = [A C]
```