# Cumulative count of unique element in Matlab array

Tags: matlab, count, unique

Working with Matlab 2019b.

```
x = [10 10 10 20 20 30]';
```

How do I get a cumulative count of unique elements in `x`, which should look like:

```
y = [1 2 3 1 2 1]';
```

**EDIT**:

My real array is actually much longer than the example given above. Below are the methods I tested:

```
x = randi([1 100], 100000, 1);
x = sort(x);

% method 1: check neighboring values in one loop
tic
y = ones(size(x));
for ii = 2:length(x)
    if x(ii) == x(ii-1)
        y(ii) = y(ii-1) + 1;
    end
end
toc

% method 2 (Wolfie): count occurrence of unique values explicitly
tic
u = unique(x);
y = zeros(size(x));
for ii = 1:numel(u)
    idx = (x == u(ii));
    y(idx) = 1:nnz(idx);
end
toc

% method 3 (Luis Mendo): triangular matrix
tic
y = sum(triu(x==x'))';
toc
```

Results:

```
Method 1: Elapsed time is 0.016847 seconds.
Method 2: Elapsed time is 0.037124 seconds.
Method 3: Elapsed time is 10.350002 seconds.
```

Comment: Will `x` always be sorted as in your example?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count repeating integers in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54079558/count-repeating-integers-in-an-array)

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**:
Assuming that `x` is sorted:

```
x = [10 10 10 20 20 30].';
x = sort(x);

d = [1 ;diff(x)];
f = find(d);
d(f) = f;
ic = cummax(d);
y = (2 : numel(x) + 1).' - ic;
```

When `x` is unsorted use this:

```
[s, is] = sort(x);
d = [1 ;diff(s)];
f = find(d);
d(f) = f;
ic = cummax(d);
y(is) = (2 : numel(s) + 1).' - ic;
```

*Original Answer that only works on GNU Octave:*
Assuming that `x` is sorted:

```
x = [10 10 10 20 20 30].';
x = sort(x);

[~, ic] = cummax(x);
y = (2 : numel(x) + 1).' - ic;
```

When `x` is unsorted use this:

```
[s, is] = sort(x);
[~, ic] = cummax(s);
y(is) = (2 : numel(s) + 1).' - ic;
```

Comment: In MATLAB r2022b, cummax doesn't seem to have a second output argument.

Comment: Thanks! GNU Octave has a second output and question here is about MATLAB. I updated the answer.

Comment: Nice! The updated version is even faster than the one I posted in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

You could loop over the unique elements, and set their indices to `1:n` each time...

```
u = unique(x);
y = zeros(size(x));
for ii = 1:numel(u)
    idx = (x == u(ii));
    y(idx) = 1:nnz(idx);
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a little inefficient because it generates an intermediate matrix, when actually only a triangular half is needed:

```
y = sum(triu(x==x.')).';
```

Comment: This is concise but as you said inefficient. Turns out it's not just a little :)  My real array is much longer. See my edits.

Comment: I see. It would have helped if you had included that information from the beginning :-)

Comment: Anyway, in my comparisons the matrix method fares between the other two you used in your timing, as long as the required matrix fits in the available memory. I'm using R2017b

Answer (score 1):

Here's a no-for-loop version. On my machine it's a bit faster than the previous working methods:

```matlab
% if already sorted, can omit this first and last line
[s, is] = sort(x);
[u,~,iu] = unique(s);
c = accumarray(iu,1);
cs = cumsum([0;c]);
z = (1:numel(x))'-repelem(cs(1:end-1),c);
y(is) = z;
```