# increment occurrences of repeated elements by one - matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector

```
v = [1,2,1,1,1,2,2]
```

`1` and `2` are my two groups. I'm trying to increment each group by 1 every time there is a repetition

The desired result:

```
v2 = 
    1  1  2  3  4  2  3
```

I tried the functions `cumsum` and `movsum` with `splitapply`, but nothing has worked so far

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count repeating integers in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54079558/count-repeating-integers-in-an-array)

Comment: @obchardon I knew I had seen this (or something very similar) somewhere! However, in your question all equal values are adjacent, which simplifies the problem a little and allows for more approaches. [This](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/178500/36398) PPCG challenge, linked in your question, may be a more exact "duplicate", but of course it won't contain the most practical approaches...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using different values of `v` for more clarity:

```
v = [10, 20, 10, 10, 10, 20, 20];
```

- Memory-efficient solution, with a loop over the unique values of `v`:

  ```
  [a, ~, c] = unique(v);
  v2 = zeros(size(v));
  for k = 1:numel(a)
      ind = c==k;
      v2(ind) = 1:sum(ind); 
  end
  ```
- Memory-inefficient (it builds an intermediate `N`×`N` matrix, `N = numel(v)`), but simpler:

  ```
  v2 = sum(triu(v==v.'));
  ```
- Another approach, probably memory-efficient too:

  ```
  s = sparse(c, 1:numel(c), 1);
  v2 = nonzeros(s.*cumsum(s, 2)).';
  ```

Comment: Your first solution is the same as mine, but somehow more complicated. :)

Comment: @CrisLuengo You are right, I could have avoided the third output of `unique`

Answer (score 2):

If you have few groups, you could iterate over the groups. As the number of groups increases this might become expensive though.

```matlab
v = [1,2,1,1,1,2,2];

v2 = zeros(size(v));
for p = unique(v)
  i = v == p;
  v2(i) = 1:sum(i);
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You say you only have 2 groups, so you can just add the cumulative sums of the Boolean when equal to one or the other

```
idx = (v==1);
v2 = cumsum(idx).*idx + cumsum(~idx).*(~idx);
```

For your example,

```
v = [1,2,1,1,1,2,2];
v2 = [1,1,2,3,4,2,3]
```

In the more generic case where you have more than two values, you can generalise this using implicit expansion at the cost of memory

```
idx = v == (unique(v).');
v2 = sum( cumsum(idx,2) .* idx );
```